# R studio one multi core CPU or dual single cores CPUS

Tags: r, server, cpu, multicore

So far I was using R on my home pc: i3 CPU, two cores, 4 threads. In order to run the code faster I was using the package "DoSnow", utilizing 3 out of the 4 cores in order not to choke my system completely.

However, now I got a server which has a two single core Xenons and I wonder: can I use the same multi core code for multi cpus? If no, how can I run them together and at about 70% (again, in order to not choke the system)? So far, all the codes I found on the net refer to cores rather then cpus.

Comment: From using my own I've found it aggregates all the cores and parses work that way. Be careful with large datasets split across multiple nodes (physical CPUs) I've noticed arithmetic inconsistencies when using <100% of cores to perform operations. Your computer is designed not to choke itself, give it everything! At least that's been my experience.